# Openssl: What RSA Signature scheme is supported by RSA_verify() ?

Tags: c, linux, openssl, rsa

As per my understanding there are two RSA signature schemes - PSS (Probabilistic Signature Scheme) and the old PKCS1-v1_5:

Can I use RSA_verify() API to check RSA signature under both schemes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent version - see: http://fixunix.com/openssl/526614-signing-verifying-messages-rsassa-pss.html for how to use it.